# Calling multiple functions with multiple params from a function pointer?

Tags: c++

I am trying to define a function pointer for calling multiple functions with different parameters but now I am stuck with my idea does anyone have a idea or can see what i do wrong because i can't :smile: It will be very helpful if you can help me.

```
//Goal:  Calling the sum function from the function pointer with the t1 struct as parameter
//Theory:  As my theory after first param the function will go  -4 down in memory and look for the second variable but nope
float sum(float &x, float &y) //a random test-foo function
{
    float s = x + y;
    printf_s("(%X)x: %f + (%X)y: %f | Result: %f\n",&x, x, &y, y, s);
    return s;

}
typedef float(*fsum)(void* params);
fsum fsm = (fsum)&sum;
struct t1 {
    float f[2]; //the params will be here
}tx1;
int main()
{
    tx1.f[0] = 4.3; tx1.f[1] = 2;  //setting values on the params
    printf_s("tx1: 0x%X\ntx1.f[0]: 0x%X\ntx1.f[1]: 0x%X\n", &tx1, &tx1.f[0], &tx1.f[1]);
    fsm(&tx1.f[0]); //calling the function pointer
    getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

My main goal is to use this later to call different functions with different parameters with just 1 function pointer and with 1 pointer to the params
like:

```
if(statement1)
    funcPointer = func1; //change the func pointer to point to func1
else if(statement1)
    funcPointer = func2;  //change the func pointer to point to func2
funcPointer(paramPointer); //call the function pointer
```

And a second question: Let's say i have a .dll that i wrote in C++  it's have a function called "fuu" i have the dll loaded in an another process how can i load the "fuu" function with a second different C++ dll?

Comment: One question per post please

Comment: Please decide if this is to be for C++ or for C and set the tag accordingly. If you have a second question, please post that in a separate question and do not try to combine multiple questions in a single posting especially when they appear to be different topics so would have answers that are not in the same area of expertise.

Comment: Why do you want to take this approach? I ask because the design of C++ is about not doing it this way and you are fighting the language. It is as if you are wanting to write C code with C++. And hard to read and understand C code as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like your pattern, but if you really insist on it, you could use polymorphism.

```
class BaseProcessor{
      public:
      virtual float func(void *); };

class Processor1 : public BaseProcessor {
      public:
      type3 func(void * param){ 
           type3 func1((type1*) param);
      }

      private:
           type3 func1(type1 * param){
            //implementation goes here
           }         };


class Processor2 : public BaseProcessor {
      public:
      type3 func(void * param){ 
           return func2((type2 *) param);
      }

      private:
           type3 func2(type2 * param){
            //implementation goes here
           }
    };
```

And use it like this.

```
    BaseProcessor * processor;

    if(statement1)
        processor = new Processor1; 
    else if(statement1)
        processor = new Processor2; 

    processor->func(paramPointer);
```

`void *` is a warning of a bad C++ design.

If you don't have ambiguous signatures you could just plainly overload `func()`, or just attach the implementation to the data:

```
class base_t{
    public:
    virtual float sum();
}

class t1 : public base_t {
    public:
    float f[2]; //the params will be here

    sum(){/* Implemenation goes here*/}
};
```